# Figuring Out a Java Method in a Simple Pong Game

Tags: java, android

I'm referring to the following open source Android pong game:
https://github.com/Grarak/Pong-Android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/grarak/pong

I can understand all of the methods and how they work by debugging the code and seeing which method and which condition fires according to what happens on the screen. But there is one method in the whole project that I cannot figure out its purpose, although it is heavily used whenever the ball hits the edges of the screen. I just can't figure out why it is calculated the way it is, and what is the logic of its algorithm.

The method in question is named "getVelocityY" and it's at the bottom of this page:
https://github.com/Grarak/Pong-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/grarak/pong/Ball.java

Would appreciate any help you can give in figuring this part out. I'll be glad to answer any question you may have and if you'd like I documented the other methods of the project in simple English, in case you'd want that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a breakdown of that method, even though this is not really a suitable question for SO....

```
private double getVelocityY(Paddle paddle, float radius) {
```

Set up 5 hitboxes to determine in what region the ball hit the padddle

```
    Float[][] hitboxes = new Float[5][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < hitboxes.length; i++) {
```

Calculate the minimum and maximum positions for this hitbox

```
        hitboxes[i][0] = (paddle.getLength() / hitboxes.length) * i + paddle.getHeight();
        hitboxes[i][1] = (paddle.getLength() / hitboxes.length) * (i + 1) + paddle.getHeight();
```

Extend the hitboxes at the edges to make sure that the edgeo of the ball (with given radius) will still hit the paddle. Note: this code could have been moved out of the iteration.

```
        if (i == 0) hitboxes[i][0] -= radius;
        else if (i == hitboxes.length - 1) hitboxes[i][1] += radius;
    }
```

Determine the change in velocity based on where the ball hit the paddle. If it hit the center, the velocity is unchanged.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < hitboxes.length; i++) {
        if (position.y > hitboxes[i][0] && position.y < hitboxes[i][1])
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    return -4;
                case 4:
                    return 4;
                case 1:
                    return -2;
                case 3:
                    return 2;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So if I understand it correctly, when i==2 it means that it's right in the middle of the paddle, and that's why there is no "case" statement for when i==2 ?

Comment: Correct! The paddle is divided into 5 segments represented by hitboxes. They are numbered 0,1,2,3,4. The outer ones (0 & 4) result in a big change in velocity, the ones next to that (1 & 3) cause a smaller change. The middle one (2) has no effect. I seem to remember that the game of pong works like that... When hitting the paddle on the side, the ball speeds up and moves awat at a sharper angle.

Comment: Sorry but I actually still don't understand it, because the method gets only 1 of the 2 paddles in the game, so why is the 2nd dimension of the array needed? I thought it uses 5 hitboxes for each paddle, but it actually uses 10 hit boxes overall for a single paddle, and I don't understand why they need to be duplicated (2 arrays of 5).

Comment: Each hitbox has a minimum and maximum value

Comment: ohhhh now I see what you mean! Thank you again!